# Why is the request param of my ag-grid undefined?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Hey I'm testing the ServerSide RowModel of Ag-Grid with Angular. I will add my response from the server later, since my goal is to learn the framework first. I want to print out the request parameter of my grid in `console.log(Start Row: ${params.request.startRow}, End Row: ${params.request.endRow})` but I get undefined for both params. Does anyone know the reason?

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  gridApi!: GridApi;

  columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
    {field: 'firstName'},
    {field: 'lastName'},
  ];

  gridOptions: GridOptions = {
    columnDefs: this.columnDefs,
    rowModelType: 'serverSide',
    cacheBlockSize: 5,
    maxBlocksInCache: 1,
    sideBar: true,
  }
  
  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  dataSource: IServerSideDatasource = {
    getRows: (params: IServerSideGetRowsParams) => {
      console.log(`Start Row: ${params.request.startRow}, End Row: ${params.request.endRow}`)
      params.success({
        rowData: [{firstName: "Test", lastName: "test"},
          {firstName: "test", lastName: "test"},]
      })
    }
  }

  
  onGridReady(event: AgGridEvent) {
    this.gridApi = event.api
    this.gridApi.setServerSideDatasource(this.dataSource);
  }
```

my TestComponent html file:

```
<ag-grid-angular
  style="width: 100%; height: 800px"
  class="ag-theme-alpine-dark"
  [gridOptions] = "gridOptions"
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

Comment: Please reproduce the problem online (e.g StackBlitz). Does `params` even contain anything? What you expect `dataSource: IServerSideDatasource` to do?

Answer (score 0):

Inside `onGridReady` event, try to access `gridApi` on provided `gridOptions` as -

```
onGridReady(event: AgGridEvent) {
    this.gridOptions.api?.setServerSideDatasource(this.dataSource);
  }
```

Here, as you are using `gridOptions` to pass the grid configurations so we need to call the grid api on `gridOptions` only as per the official documentation of ag-grid.

For details, please check the link - https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/grid-interface/

Please let me know in case you still face any issue, I will try to help you.

Thanks.